# database to csv in django using python

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv

I am writing this small code which is part of my Django application. It is supposed to pick up data from a DB table(MySql) and make a csv file. May be its a very simple error I am getting, but I am not able to resolve it.

Name of the file: write_to_csv.py

```
import csv  
def createCSV():  
    from django.db import connection, transaction  
    cursor = connection.cursor()  
    cursor.execute("select * from avg_max_min;")  
    csv_writer = csv.writer(open("out.csv", "wt"), delimiter=',')  
    csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description]) # write headers  
    csv_writer.writerows(cursor)  
    del csv_writer # this will close the CSV file
```

**Error**
Exception Value:
'module' object has no attribute 'writer'
Exception Location: C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\report\src\report  ..\report\report_view\write_to_csv.py in createCSV, line 6

Comment: if you go into a django shell and do:
`import csv`
followed by
`csv.writer`
what does it say?

Comment: Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import csv
>>> csv.writer
<built-in function writer>
>>> csv.writer(open("out.csv","wb"))
<_csv.writer object at 0x014E2990>

Comment: there you have it... must be something else in your code. you might get better help if you post the whole thing somewhere.

Comment: I have posted the entire file which is using csv. Do u think there is somethg Django not supporting in csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open`'s second argument should be `wb` not `wt`.  Other than that, it looks like you are doing everything right.

If it's still not working, can you update your question with the results of doing `dir(csv)`? (It's most likely that you have some other module installed in your Python distribution or in the same directory as `write_to_csv.py` with the same name.)

Comment: I tried the first thg and its not working. Please elaborate more about dir(csv)..I did not understand it. Plus I am sure I dono not have any file named write_to_csv.py other than this one.

Comment: @Compuser7 - `dir` simply provides what's publicly available in a module.  I suspect that you have some other file in the same place `write_to_csv.py` is named `csv.py` -- either that, or you have another module named csv that's shadowing the built-in module (but apparently only in your running environment, since you can access it via the shell.)

Comment: >>> dir(csv)
['Dialect', 'DictReader', 'DictWriter', 'Error', 'QUOTE_ALL', 'QUOTE_MINIMAL', '
QUOTE_NONE', 'QUOTE_NONNUMERIC', 'Sniffer', 'StringIO', '_Dialect', '__all__', '
__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__',
'excel', 'excel_tab', 'field_size_limit', 'get_dialect', 'list_dialects', 're',
'reader', 'reduce', 'register_dialect', 'unregister_dialect', 'writer']

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's a setup problem (something like [this](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tutor/82660/)). Make sure you don't have a file named csv.py or some other weirdness that is "hiding" python's `csv` module.